# ILOG dynamic ruleset

Tags: ilog, jrules, ibm-odm

```
public void executeRules(IlrRule[] rules){
       IlrRuleset rulesetNew = new IlrRuleset();
       IlrContext ctxt = new IlrContext(rulesetNew);
       IlrTask task = ruleset.getTask("ExecFlow#exe");
       IlrRuleTaskRunner runner = ctxt.getRuleTaskRunner(task);
       runner.setActiveRules(rules);
       int fired = 0;
       runner.runInitialActions();
       fired += runner.runBody();
       runner.runFinalActions();

}
```

How we can create a dynamic ruleset from group of rules? this group is a dynamic.
I am using IBM ODM 8.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Java implementation are disappeared, we used ***irl*** language, this is the solution :

We defined the scope and we select the rules dynamically

```
scope= {exe.R05,exe.R04,exe.R03}

body = dynamicselect() {
    return selectedFunction(context.getRuleset().allRules);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just be careful with dynamic selects. If you have a lot of rules, it can increase the execution time of the rule set significantly.

Answer (score 0):

```
body = dynamicselect() {    
    return selectedFunction(context.getRuleset().allRules);    
}
```

Is sufficient to custom the rules which you like to executed.